# salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
<ltng:require
styles="/resource/slds090/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>
<aura:attribute name="expenses" type="Expense__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="newExpense" type="Expense__c"
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Expense__c',
'Name': '',
'Amount__c': 0,
'Client__c': '',
'Date__c': '',
'Reimbursed__c': false
}"/>
<!-- If you registered a namespace, replace the previous aura:attribute tags with the
following -->
<!-- <aura:attribute name="expenses" type="myNamespace.Expense__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="newExpense" type="myNamespace__Expense__c"
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'myNamespace__Expense__c',
'Name': '',
'myNamespace__Amount__c': 0,
'myNamespace__Client__c': '',
'myNamespace__Date__c': '',
'myNamespace__Reimbursed__c': false
}"/> -->
<!-- Attributes for Expense Counters -->
<aura:attribute name="total" type="Double" default="0.00" />
<aura:attribute name="exp" type="Double" default="0" />
<!-- Input Form using components -->
<div class="container">
<form class="slds-form--stacked">
<div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<!-- If you registered a namespace,
the attributes include your namespace.
For example, value="{!v.newExpense.myNamespace__Amount__c}" -->
<ui:inputText aura:id="expname" label="Expense Name"
class="slds-input"
labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
value="{!v.newExpense.Name}"
required="true"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<ui:inputNumber aura:id="amount" label="Amount"
class="slds-input"
labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
value="{!v.newExpense.Amount__c}"

placeholder="20.80" required="true"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<ui:inputText aura:id="client" label="Client"
class="slds-input"
labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
value="{!v.newExpense.Client__c}"
placeholder="ABC Co."/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="expdate" label="Expense Date"
class="slds-input"
labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
value="{!v.newExpense.Date__c}"
displayDatePicker="true"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="reimbursed" label="Reimbursed?"
class="slds-checkbox"
labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
value="{!v.newExpense.Reimbursed__c}"/>
<ui:button label="Submit"
class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
labelClass="label"
press="{!c.createExpense}"/>
</div>
</form>
</div><!-- ./container-->
<!-- Expense Counters -->
<div class="container slds-p-top--medium">
<div class="row">
<div class="slds-tile ">
<!-- Make the counter red if total amount is more than 100 -->
<div class="{!v.total >= 100
? 'slds-notify slds-notify--toast slds-theme--error
slds-theme--alert-texture'
: 'slds-notify slds-notify--toast slds-theme--alert-texture'}">
<p class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate">Total Expenses</p>
$<ui:outputNumber class="slds-truncate" value="{!v.total}"
format=".00"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-tile ">
<div class="slds-notify slds-notify--toast slds-theme--alert-texture">
<p class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate">No. of Expenses</p>
<ui:outputNumber class="slds-truncate" value="{!v.exp}"/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!-- Display expense records -->
<div class="container slds-p-top--medium">
<div id="list" class="row">
<aura:iteration items="{!v.expenses}" var="expense">
<!-- If you’re using a namespace,
use the format
{!expense.myNamespace__myField__c} instead. -->
<p>{!expense.Name}, {!expense.Client__c},
{!expense.Amount__c}, {!expense.Date__c},
{!expense.Reimbursed__c}</p>
</aura:iteration>
</div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

giving error like `<apex:component>` is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1,,please guide me how to fix.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing to get this error? A Lightning Component is not created via Setup's Visualforce Components screen.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are working throught the lightning component developer guide. It's very difficult to read your code without proper indentation but I do notice that where the [guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf) states has "myNamespace" you are not replacing it with your namespace. Take a look at page 42 were it talks about what to do with the namespace depending on if your org has one or not:

> Using Your Organization’s Namespace
>
> If your organization has set a namespace prefix, use that namespace to
>   reference Lightning components, events, custom objects and fields, and
>   other items in your Lightning markup.
>
> The following items use your organization’s namespace when your
>   organization has a namespace prefix set.
>
> • References to components that you’ve created
>
> • References to events that you’ve defined
>
> • References to custom objects
>
> • References to custom fields on standard and custom objects
>
> • References to Apex controllers
>
> • References to static resources
>
> Note: Support for the c namespace in organizations that have set a
>   namespace prefix is incomplete. The following items can 
>   use the c namespace if you prefer to use the shortcut, but it’s not
>   currently a recommended practice.
>
> • References to components that you’ve created when used in Lightning
>   markup, but not in expressions or JavaScript
>
> • References to events that you’ve defined when used in Lightning
>   markup, but not in expressions or JavaScript
>
> • References to custom objects when used in component and event type
>   and default system attributes, but not in expressions or JavaScript